# Is there a way to limit model field creation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm using Rails 3.2 and are sharing a database with another system. 
In this database, there are some tables which have +- 300 fields (work with the other system) and some of those fields are large and are useless for my system.

What I need is a way to limit field creation **in the model**. For instance:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
   // put something here that limit field creation 
   attr_accessible :codent, :nomeusual
end
```

This way, when someone creates an object in Controller, only the requiring fields would be available and reading and writing would be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ActiveModel::Dirty` with `before_save` callback and raise an exception if attribute was changed.

Comment: What I need is something that would make Rails limit its field creation in the SELECT.
    class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
       // put something here that limit field creation 
       attr_accessible :codent, :nomeusual
    end

When (in console) I code:
cust = Customer.find(1)

Rails would fetch:
SELECT CODENT, NOMEUSUAL FROM CUSTOMER WHERE ID = 1